# My application jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

I have a registration form:

```
<div id ="regis" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
   <form >
    <p>
    Fisrt Name:
     <input id="fname1" class="input" type ="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      Last Name:
        <input id="lname1" class="input" type ="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        NIC Number:
        <input id="nic" class="input" type ="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        Email Address:
        <input id="eml" class="input" type ="text"/>
    </p>
       <p>
```

%0s�'�-q�
 "# ?�UmlIqc7,`�oe"er:

Save

This is my jQuery separate `re.js` file code. That I need to validate above form. Unfortunately this is not validating.

```
$(document).ready(function (event){
$("#sub").click(function(){  //submit btn
   var  ffname = $("#fname1"); //fisrst name
   var  lname = $("#lname1");
   var  nic = $("#nic");
   var  eml1 = $("#eml");
   var  tp = $("#tp");


    if(ffname.val() ==""){
        $("this").css("background-color" , "red");
    }
    else
    {
        $("this").css("background-color" , "green");
    }

    if(nic.length <10 || nic.length>10 || nic.length <=0)
    {
        alert("please enter correct NIC Number");
    }
    else if(nic.length ==10)
    {

        var a = nic.substr(0,2);
        alert("your birth year is:"+a);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: And include applicaple html and ask a question also. No idea what this is about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to achieve through new HTML5 attributes (required and pattern) and CSS3, see fiddle below:

```
<li>
     <label for="nic">NIC Number:</label>
     <input id="nic" type="text" pattern = "^\d{10}$" required />
</li>
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/907rLppm/)

New HTML5 attributes allow you to add regex patterns that will apply to the corresponding input. Then using CSS3 to apply styles based on the :valid or :invalid responses for visual feedback for the user. Note: forms will not be submitted until all fields are valid.

Also, try to use an `<ul>` in your `<form>` markup as opposed to a `<p>` to order your form elements.

Comment: finally i found my mistake.it solved.thank you all support to me. :)